# What do i write down in system.out.println

Tags: java, printing

```html
public class bida { 

    public class void main(String [] args) {        
        sameDiagonalF(20,53);
    }
    
    public static boolean sameDiagonalB(int sq1, int sq2) {
        return ((sq2-sq1) % 2 != 0);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Hello, i need help here.. my question was to check if the two squares are on the
same backward diagonal.

For instance : 
sameDiagonalB(70, 16) => true

Is my coding correct? or anything to fix here or add on the main etc. and.. what do I write down on the "System.out.println(???)" <-- (inside the bracket?) As i'm having difficulty with most of it on the systemoutprintln. Thank you

Comment: As i want my output to be either "true" or "false". For example if (70, 16), the answer is true

Comment: You can not use a command after return

Comment: In the coding, it should be sameDiagonalB(20,53); not sameDiagonalF. sorry

Comment: so.. how should I fix it so there will be an output that shows either true or false? because I tried System.out.println("sameDiagonalB"); it shows the error , unreachable code

Answer (score 2):

```
public class void main(String [] args) {
    sameDiagonalB(20,53);
        }

        public static boolean sameDiagonalB(int sq1, int sq2) {
            System.out.println((sq2-sq1) % 2 != 0);
        return ((sq2-sq1) % 2 != 0);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve `println` problem, keep it in mind that nothing after `return` runs. It exists the method as soon as `return` is called.

May be you wanted:

```
public class void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(sameDiagonalB(20,53));
}

public static boolean sameDiagonalB(int sq1, int sq2) {
    return ((sq2-sq1) % 2 != 0);
}
```

Or,

```
public class void main(String [] args) {
    sameDiagonalB(20,53);
}

public static void sameDiagonalB(int sq1, int sq2) {
    System.out.println(sq1 + " and " + sq2 + " same diagonal = " + ((sq2-sq1) % 2 != 0));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah i see.. Thank you guys! Now I know and will always remember that nothing will comes after "return". and.. there are many ways to show the output result. quite impressive for me as I only just started to learn programming hehe. thank you! :)

Comment: You should also read this on `return` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html